# Next 13 with Wordpress fetch data on server fails on build but not in development

Tags: next.js, fetch-api

Everything works fine in development but when I do npm run build it fails giving me this error:

`info  - Collecting page data [    ] info  - Generating static pages (0/5)DynamicServerError: Dynamic server usage: no-store fetch`

As I can understand it has to do with **fetching** the data on the server and perhaps with **caching**.

This is my **`getData()` function** where I get the data from graphql.

```js
const getData = async (query: string) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await fetch("MY ENDPOINT", {
      method: "POST",
      cache: "no-store", // Maybe this causes the issue, but when I change this to forced cache it doesn't work on development.
      next: {
        revalidate: 1, 
      },
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        query: query,
      }),
    }).then((res) => res.json());

    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

export default getData;
```

This is my **query:**

```js
export const getPostBySlug = (slug: string) => {
  const getPost = `
  query PostBySlug {
    postBy(slug: "${slug}") {
      id
      content(format: RENDERED)
      title
      date
    }
  }
    `;

  return getPost;
};
```

And this is **how I call the data** in my component:

```js
export default async function Post({
  params: { post },
}: {
  params: { post: string };
}) {
  const { postBy } = await getData(getPostBySlug(post));
  
  return (
    <article>
     {* Content....*}
      // The rest of the content is irrelevant to the question
    </article>
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm noticing something similar using the @vercel/kv package: https://github.com/vercel/storage/issues/213

Comment: No unfortunately I haven't found any solution yet :/